# How do I implement Download Count?

Tags: 7, views, files

I am trying to sort my view of documents by "most downloaded".  I see that there are only a few modules, Download_Count being one. There is no documentation on how to implement this.

I have installed it and can't see any way to actually use it.  Or is there a newer module at this point?

I have spent days of research and can't come up with anything. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

For **[download count](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_count)** you will have to enable one of the provided blocks after installing

> four blocks: top downloaded files, top downloaded users, top downloaders, and top nodes of file downloads.

**[File download count](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_download_count)** might also be a good candidate.  The links to the downloads have to created manually (using a module) or with the use of views if they are to be counted. A link has to look like this `file/[file:fid]/download`

In the simplest case you can create a view that lists all the files to be counted and using `file:fid` field and then rewrite that field to create a link that looks like this`<a href="file/[file:fid]/download">download</a>`

or if above don't work for you you might want to give [ajax download count](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_dlcount) ac chance

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I realize that Download Count will not work for me since my files are stored publicly.  I will look at the second one you mention - File Download Count.  I did install the AJAX one and see that it provides "X download(s)" next to each file.  I could not get it to increment even after confirming that Javascript was enabled in my browser. So I have no idea how to get that to work.